# How to achieve dot builder syntax in Python?

Tags: python

Before you ask "what the f*!k is dot builder syntax", let me show you what I want.

I want a syntax similar to this, which is written in GoLang:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    parasut "github.com/ozgur-yalcin/parasut.go/src"
)

func main() {
        request := new(parasut.Request)
        request.SalesInvoice.Data.Attributes.ItemType = "invoice"     // << Değişiklik yapmayınız !
        request.SalesInvoice.Data.Attributes.Description = ""         // Fatura başlığı
        request.SalesInvoice.Data.Attributes.IssueDate = ""           
        
        request.SalesInvoice.Data.Relationships.Contact = new(parasut.SingleRelationShip)
        request.SalesInvoice.Data.Relationships.Contact.Data = new(parasut.RelationShip)
        request.SalesInvoice.Data.Relationships.Contact.Data.Type = "contacts" // << Değişiklik yapmayınız !
        request.SalesInvoice.Data.Relationships.Contact.Data.ID = ""           
                ...
}
```

I achieved same functionality with

```py
         parasut.create_invoice(
                sales_invoice_form=ParasutCreateSalesInvoiceRequest(
                    data=ParasutCreateSalesInvoiceRequestData(
                        type="sales_invoices",
                        attributes=ParasutSalesInvoiceCreateUpdateAttributes(
                            net_total=1.00,
                            item_type="invoice",
                            description="",
                            issue_date=datetime.date.today(),
                            ...
                        ),
                        relationships=ParasutCreateSalesInvoiceRequestDataRelationships(
                            details=ParasutCreateSalesInvoiceRequestDataRelationshipsDetails(
                                data=sales_invoice_details
                            ),
                            contact=ParasutCreatePurchaseBillBasicRequestDataRelationshipsSupplier(
                                data=ParasutCreatePurchaseBillBasicRequestDataRelationshipsSupplierData(
                                    id=contact_id,
                                    type="contacts",
                                )
                            ),
                        ),
                    )
                )
            )
```

in Python,but as you can see, this is nowhere as clean as the dot syntax. I have to import and use classes for building requests, which really gets on my nerves.

I generated the client & models with https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator and here is the definition https://apidocs.parasut.com/swagger.json if you want to generate and see the client yourself.

I am using Pydantic BaseModels, that got generated from the openapi-generator.

thanks in advance.

In according to the first answer, I dont want to lose type hint support. I still want to have Pyright support of classes, but I want dot notation somehow.

Comment: for each function, just return the same object but with the updated changes, its called "function linking"

Comment: What? Should I make builder functions for each classes? @DeanVanGreunen

Comment: "Nowhere near as clean". It's not supposed to be; you're initializing an object by initializing its nested fields four to six layers deep. The syntax *shouldn't* make this easy; it's a very good indicator that you should split this thing up into multiple parts: for instance, a function that makes the `attributes` and one that makes the `relationships`. *Neither* of the code blocks you've posted are clean, but at least the Python one makes the nesting clear, rather than just making everything flat.

Comment: It was nice doxxing myself for a millisecond. You say i should do something like this, and import / use this only in the relationships parameter? https://pastebin.com/4ZWxjYbU @SilvioMayolo

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
class Dotted:
    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'd', {})

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item not in self.d:
            self.d[item] = Dotted()
        return self.d[item]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.d[key] = value

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            k: v.to_dict() if isinstance(v, Dotted) else v
            for k, v in self.d.items()
        }

## example:


request = Dotted()

request.SalesInvoice.Data.Attributes.ItemType = "invoice"
request.SalesInvoice.Data.Attributes.Description = "1"
request.SalesInvoice.Data.Attributes.IssueDate = "2"

request.SalesInvoice.Data.Relationships.Contact.Data.Type = "contacts"
request.SalesInvoice.Data.Relationships.Contact.Data.ID = "3"

print(request.to_dict())
```

Comment: I would lose any Pyright / Mypy support with this right? Main thing I went with openapi-swagger is, it literally supports type hinting to the fullest with Pydantic classes etc. I will look into this as a last resort if I cant find anything, thanks mate!